# Sort array string which begins with a letter

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, node-webkit

How i can sort this array list to be sure all files starting with `_` will be first?

**Context**: is for a loader and i want to be sure to load all files with `_` first.

List are generate random from a scan, so i can never be sure about the order.

```
0:"js\game\global\app.js"
1:"js\game\global\camera.js"
2:"js\game\global\displayGroups.js"
3:"js\game\global\dataBase.js"
4:"js\game\global\mouse.js"
5:"js\game\global\loaders.js"
6:"js\game\global\stage.js"
7:"js\game\global\polyfill.js"
8:"js\game\scenes\scene_boot.js"
9:"js\game\scenes\scene_IntroVideo.js"
10:"js\game\scenes\scene_loader.js"
11:"js\game\scenes\scene_Map1.js"
12:"js\game\scenes\_scene_base.js" //need to be alway first
13:"js\game\scenes\scene_Title.js"
```

So in this example, after sorting, the file `_scene_base` should be first.

Here is my test code, but it is revealed unstable and I don't know why, sometime it not work.

```
 files.sort((a,b) => {return a.indexOf("\_")>-1?-files.indexOf(a):0 });
```

sorry if my english are poor guys.

Comment: please add an array as data and the wanted result, after sorting. what is first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution based on `indexOf` and only the first position of the underscore.

```js
const arr = [
  'js\\game\\global\\app.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\camera.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\displayGroups.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\dataBase.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\mouse.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\loaders.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\stage.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\polyfill.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_boot.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_IntroVideo.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_loader.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Map1.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Title.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\_scene_base.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Loader.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\_scenebase.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\sceneTit_le.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_introVide_o.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\sceneIntroVi_deo.js',
];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
   const ai = a.indexOf('_');
   const bi = b.indexOf('_');
   return (ai > -1 && bi > -1 && (ai - bi)) || -1;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place **any file that starts with underscore** first in order, filter and concatenate it.

```js
const arr = ['js\\game\\global\\app.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\camera.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\displayGroups.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\dataBase.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\mouse.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\loaders.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\stage.js',
  'js\\game\\global\\polyfill.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_boot.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_IntroVideo.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_loader.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Map1.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\_scene_base.js',
  'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Title.js'
]

const _files = arr.filter(e => e.indexOf('\\_') !== -1).sort()
const files = arr.filter(e => e.indexOf('\\_') === -1).sort()

const arr2 = _files.concat(files)

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply replace underscore for sorting and get this strings on top of the directory.

```js
var array = ["js\\game\\global\\app.js", "js\\game\\global\\camera.js", "js\\game\\global\\displayGroups.js", "js\\game\\global\\dataBase.js", "js\\game\\global\\mouse.js", "js\\game\\global\\loaders.js", "js\\game\\global\\stage.js", "js\\game\\global\\polyfill.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\scene_boot.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\scene_IntroVideo.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\scene_loader.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Map1.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\_scene_base.js", "js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Title.js"]

array.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/_/g, ' ').localeCompare(b.replace(/_/g, ' ')));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Array.sort()` passing in your own custom comparator and use `String.startWith()` to check whether a filename starts with "_" or not:
Try the following:

```js
let arr =['js\\game\\global\\app.js', 'js\\game\\global\\camera.js', 'js\\game\\global\\displayGroups.js', 'js\\game\\global\\dataBase.js', 'js\\game\\global\\mouse.js', 'js\\game\\global\\loaders.js', 'js\\game\\global\\stage.js', 'js\\game\\global\\polyfill.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_boot.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_IntroVideo.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_loader.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Map1.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\_scene_base.js', 'js\\game\\scenes\\scene_Title.js' ];

arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  let str1Array = a.split("\\");
  let str2Array = b.split("\\");
  return str2Array[str2Array.length-1].startsWith("_") -str1Array[str1Array.length-1].startsWith("_") 
});

console.log(arr);
```