# Sort based on startsWith in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on search. I am filtering my array based on search input. Here's my code:

```
const filtered = list.filter((m) =>
  m.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
);
```

Now I want my filtered array to be sorted based on `startsWith()`.

For example, I have an array

```
[brother, brothersmad, other]
```

and my search search input is other. I want other to be on top.

Comment: and what order should the other two be in?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I just want string starting with the search input on top.

Comment: `["brother", "brothersmad", "other"].sort((a, b) => b.startsWith('other') - a.startsWith('other'))`

Comment: `true - false?`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, that works, apparently the minus operator forces both to be cast/converted to 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: I expected that much, but still klugey in my opinion

Comment: Does't sort the array @jaromanda

Comment: yes it does @MusadiqKhan - you probably did it wrong

Comment: Should this old page receive a modern answer using this function? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10573004/2943403 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/56611426/2943403 Does Musadiq want to implement a secondary sorting criteria?

Comment: @mickmackusa - the code in the question doesn't lend itself to supply a fully fledged answer - you get what you ask for :p OP doesn't state where/how the sort should be done

Comment: @mickmackusa - that's an opinion, and you're welcome to it

Comment: Oh, i was going to add an answer now that I'm at my computer and not on a phone ... `const dosort = (array, word) => array.slice().sort((a, b) => (b.startsWith(word) - a.startsWith(word) || a.localeCompare(b)))` ... the `.slice()` may not be required if the input array is allowed to be mutated